# Scaling sum of numbers to add up to particular value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I have a sum of real numbers $A_1 + A_2 + \cdots + A_N  = A$ that add up to a known number $A$. All of the $A_1,\ldots,A_N$ are known as well.

Is there a way of scaling the $A_1,\ldots,A_N$ so that the sum of the numbers add up to another known real number $B$ instead of $A$?

So what I am searching for are $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_N$ such that:

$$A_1\gamma_1 + A_2\gamma_2 + \cdots + A_N\gamma_N  = B$$

What assumption can I make to ensure uniqueness of the $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_N$?  Is it possible to find $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_N$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make all the $\gamma$'s$= \frac BA$.  There are many other solutions-you can make the first $N-1$ anything you want and you will have a linear equation for the last one.

Comment: As long as $A_N\neq0$, anyway.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thanks, Ross; I really like the $\gamma = \frac BA$ solution.  What are the conceptual implications of making  $\gamma = \frac BA$?  What type of scaling is this?

Comment: It is just a linear scaling.  I'm not sure what you mean by conceptual implications.  It is like you graded on a scale of 0 to 5 and now want 0 to 100.  You multiply everything by 20.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thanks, Ross. That's exactly what I was looking for.